# How to print Matrix by comparing two dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, matrix, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet and there are two columns which has values in "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm" format i.e., DEP_DATE_TIME (Column F) and ARR_DATE_TIME (Column J). Row is having the same "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm" format to compare to. [Please view this image for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVtgj.png)

I am comparing Col F1 with Col L1 if its TRUE then it will return 1 and if Col J1 is >= L1 then it will return 0 otherwise 1 and by subtracting these the result is printed in its corresponding cell. Following is the formula for the same -

=IF($F$13<L1,1,0)-IF($J$13>=L1,0,1)

How can I achieve the same using python code such that it should read the sheet and plot the 0 and 1 in the cell?

How can I achieve the same using python code such that it should read the sheet and plot the 0 and 1 in the cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the pandas library in Python

```py
import pandas as pd

# Load the Excel file into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel("your_file.xlsx")

# Assuming your dates are in columns F and L, and column J for comparison
dep_date_time = pd.to_datetime(df['DEP_DATE_TIME'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
arr_date_time = pd.to_datetime(df['ARR_DATE_TIME'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
comparison_date = pd.to_datetime(df['L1'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')

# Apply your logic to create a new column with 0s and 1s
df['RESULT'] = (dep_date_time < comparison_date).astype(int) - (arr_date_time >= comparison_date).astype(int)

# Save the updated DataFrame back to Excel
df.to_excel("output_file.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: I am getting an error - KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 9
      7 dep_date_time = pd.to_datetime(df['DEP_DATE_TIME'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
      8 arr_date_time = pd.to_datetime(df['ARR_DATE_TIME'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
----> 9 comparison_date = pd.to_datetime(df['L1'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
     11 # Apply your logic to create a new column with 0s and 1s
     12 df['RESULT'] = (dep_date_time < comparison_date).astype(int) - (arr_date_time >= comparison_date).astype(int)
 KeyError: 'L1'

Comment: Dont we have to use any loop? As there will n number of rows and columns

Comment: If you can add a column name for L, we can do this easily, let me know if you can do that. Any how the above answer is generated by ChatGpt and it's wrong.

Comment: COL name for L is given in L1. Can we do it ? Could you please help me with the code? @AathilAhamed

Comment: if the col name is given the value can't be in L1 it will be in L2, did you get the point?

Comment: Could you please refer to this image? - https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVtgj.png  @AathilAhamed I am not sure how to do this...

Comment: I posted the answer @randerson

Answer (score 0):

I hope you'll achieve whatever you want, Note: this is only for the "L" column as you mentioned in the Question if you want to do that in other K, L, or M.... also you can modify it, let me know if you want any help.

```
import pandas as pd
        
# Read the Excel sheet into a DataFrame
file_path = 'your_file_path.xlsx'  # replace with your actual file path
df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
        
# Assuming your date columns are in the format 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm'
df['DEP_DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DEP_DATE_TIME'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
df['ARR_DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ARR_DATE_TIME'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
        
# Loop through columns 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', etc. until an empty column is found
start_col_index = 11 # Assuming 'l' corresponds to column index 12
for col_index in range(start_col_index, len(df.columns)):
    if df.iloc[:, col_index].isnull().all():  # Check if the column is empty for all rows
            break
        
        # Get the value from the first row of the current column
    current_column_value = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[0, col_index], errors='coerce', format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')

    # Apply the logic and update the value in the current column for each row
    df.iloc[:, col_index] = ((df[3] < current_column_value).astype(int) - (df[4] >= current_column_value).astype(int))

    
        # Write the data frame back to the Excel sheet
df.to_excel('your_file_path.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: @randerson until which column do you have to loop? give me some test cases

Comment: Until there is a blank cell @AathilAhamed

Comment: Its not printing any output

Comment: Also i have modified this query - `# Apply the logic and update the value in the current column for each row
    df.iloc[:, col_index] = ((df[3] < current_column_value).astype(int) - (df[4] >= current_column_value).astype(int))` to `df.iloc[:, 5] = ((df['DEP_DATE_TIME'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x < L1_value else 1)) - (df['ARR_DATE_TIME'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x >= L1_value else 0)))` but still i am not able to get the desired output @AathilAhamed